# pytee can not produce proper output in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a piece of code which runs well in Python 2.7.5 but doesn't work with Python 3.

The major problem is `tee.write`, which can not write to the file.

This piece of code suppose to write 20 letters `a` into the file `/tmp/tee-test-1` and `/tmp/tee-test-2` but it does not, the two files are empty…

Could any one give me some advice?

```
import sys
import os
import subprocess
#from  netsa.util.shell import *
from string import Template

__author__ = 'Brandon Sandrowicz <brandon@sandrowicz.org>'
__version__ = '0.1'

valid_modes = ['a','w']

def create_tee(files, mode, buffer_size=128):


        if mode not in valid_modes:
            raise IOError("Only valid modes to create_tee() are: %s" % ', '.join(valid_modes))

        tee_list = []
        for file in files:
            if type(file) == str:
                fp = open(file, mode)
                tee_list.append(fp)
            else:
                tee_list.append(file)

        pipe_read, pipe_write = os.pipe()
        pid = os.fork()
        if pid == 0:
            # Child -- Read bytes from the pipe and write them to the specified
            # files.
            try:
                # Close parent's end of the pipe
                os.close(pipe_write)

                bytes = os.read(pipe_read, buffer_size)
                print (bytes)
                while(bytes):
                    for file in tee_list:
                        file.write(bytes)
                        file.flush()
                        # TODO maybe add in fsync() here if the fileno() method
                        # exists on file

                    bytes = os.read(pipe_read, buffer_size)
            except:
                pass
            finally:
                os._exit(255)
        else:
            # Parent -- Return a file object wrapper around the pipe to the
            # child.
            return os.fdopen(pipe_write,'w')



if __name__ == '__main__':

    files = [ '/tmp/tee-test-1', '/tmp/tee-test-2' ]
    num_chars = 100000

    print("Writing %d chars to files (using create_tee):" % num_chars)
    for file in files:
        print(" %s" % file)
    print()

    tee = create_tee(files,mode='a')
    #print("a" * num_chars, end=' ', file=tee)
    tee.write("a" * 20)
    tee.close()
    os.wait()

    for filename in files:
        with open(filename, 'r') as fh:
            chars = len(fh.read())
            print("File '%s' has %d chars" % (filename, chars))
```

Comment: Define "don't work". Can you edit in the errors you get?

Comment: this piece of code suppose to write 20 letters a into the file '/tmp/tee-test-1' '/tmp/tee-test-2',but it doesn't, the two files are empty

Comment: just tested it, and indeed, it's behaving differently in py2 and py3…

Answer (score 0):

ok, I found that problem interesting and challenging, and finally found out what's wrong, it's said in [that document](http://python3porting.com/problems.html#reading-from-files):

> *One common problem is that the file is opened in the wrong mode. Make sure you open text files with the `'t'` flag and binary files with the `'b'` flag and you have solved many problems.*

so as you're writing data as `b""` datatype, I tried the following:

```
    for file in files:
        if type(file) == str:
            fp = open(file, mode+'b')
            tee_list.append(fp)
        else:
            tee_list.append(file)
```

and it works well:

```
File '/tmp/tee-test-1' has 20 chars
File '/tmp/tee-test-2' has 20 chars
```